# How do I sort an array of numbers in java?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Heres my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Please enter the number of values you would like to enter: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int intNumberOfNumbers = scan.nextInt();

    ArrayList <Integer> intArray = new ArrayList();

    for (int i = 0; i < intNumberOfNumbers; i++) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a value for index " + i + ":");
        int intValue = scan.nextInt();
        intArray.add(intValue);
    }        
    System.out.println(intArray);

    int intSortedArray = Arrays.sort(intArray);
}
```

I'm trying to sort an array and looked around and saw people using Arrays.sort() so I tired it but it keeps giving me an error. Help please!

Comment: [Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: "no suitable method found for sort(ArrayList<Intger>)

Comment: Well yes, you're calling `Arrays.sort` but `intArray` isn't an array - it's an `ArrayList`. Looking at the documentation for `Arrays.sort`, which method did you expect it to call? "I'm trying to sort an array" - no, you're not.

Comment: @JonSkeet how can I call the index of a ArrayList?

Comment: What do you mean? You don't "call" an index. It's unclear what you mean, but it doesn't sound particularly related to your question...

Comment: sorry not call I meant like ie. intArray[3] except i get the error that Array not found and Array List is found so how can I get the index for a number in an Array List?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your Error: `int intSortedArray = Arrays.sort(intArray);`
replace it by `Collections.sort(intArray);`

Answer (score 1):

You are facing a compilation error at the following:

```
int intSortedArray = Arrays.sort(intArray);
```

`Arrays.sort` returns a `void` and hence you cannot assign it to a variable

Also the Arrays.sort and their overloads works on arrays of primitive types and hence would not be able to process ArrayList. Hence you would end up with a compilation error.

Refer to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int[])) of Arrays.sort method to understand the correct arguments and the return types.

The correct way to sort then would be to use `Collections.sort`.

Comment: That's not the immediate problem the OP is facing. It would be a problem if the call to `Arrays.sort` found an appropriate overload, but it doesn't...

Comment: @JonSkeet Corrected my answer

Answer (score 1):

Make use of `Collections` utility class `sort()` method like this :-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Please enter the number of values you would like to enter: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int intNumberOfNumbers = scan.nextInt();

    ArrayList <Integer> intArray = new ArrayList();

    for (int i = 0; i < intNumberOfNumbers; i++) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a value for index " + i + ":");
        int intValue = scan.nextInt();
        intArray.add(intValue);
    }        
    System.out.println(intArray);

    Collections.sort(intArray); // this will sort the Integer List
 System.out.println("sorted list : "+intArray);
}
```

More about `Collections.sort()` [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)).